# Comparing data from different sources using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have two files in QGIS about restaurants in the same area.

How can I get elements that are only in the first source and not in the second and viceversa, connected to the same activity?

I also need to get the elements in common, associated to the same restaurant. The problem is that the attribute tables of the two sources are organised in different ways, there's not an univocal ID to join the sources, also the attribute "names" are slightly different between them and same cells are empty in the second source.

Comment: Do your restaurants have the exact same coordinates in your two sources (i.e. the same restaurant has the same coordinates in source 1 and 2, even if its ID is different)? Otherwise, your issue will be difficult to solve.

Comment: @ArMoraer Nope, they don't have the same coordinates :(

Comment: How do you know they are the same two lists? It could be different restaurants. Are the counts the same?

Comment: @Vesanto Yes, they could be different restaurants, some are in common, but others are only in the first source and not in the second and viceversa. They are not in equal numbers..

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.